# From JPA to NOSQL

Tags: java, nosql

I am trying to add a NOSQL data into my JPA-based application, following [this tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#cross-store).
The entity I want to add, was befored modeled without NOSQL in this way:

**Triple.java**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ConceptPk.class)
@Table(name = "triple")
public class TripleDBModel {
    protected List<Annotation> annotations;
    public Concept conceptUriSubject;
    public Concept conceptUriObject;
    public Concept conceptUriPredicate;

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade={CascadeType.ALL }, 
            fetch=FetchType.LAZY
    )   
    @JoinTable(name = "triple_has_annotation", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_subject"), @JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_object"), @JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_predicate") },          
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="annotation_id") )
    public List<Annotation> getAnnotations() {
        return annotations;
    }
    public void setAnnotations(List<Annotation> annotations) {
        this.annotations = annotations;
    }
```

**ConceptPk.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class ConceptPk implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Concept conceptUriSubject;
    public Concept conceptUriObject;
    public Concept conceptUriPredicate;

    @Id 
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_subject")
    public Concept getConceptUriSubject() {
        return conceptUriSubject;
    }
    public void setConceptUriSubject(Concept conceptUriSubject) {
        this.conceptUriSubject = conceptUriSubject;
    }
```

I am omiting repetitions, but the 3 `Concept`s are part of the primary key, of the @Id.
Adapting this entity to NOSQL:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ConceptPk.class)
@Table(name = "triple")
@NodeEntity(partial = true)
public class TripleDBModel {
//Fields referring other entities shouldn't be initialized
    protected List<Annotation> annotations;
    //public Concept conceptUriSubject;
    //public Concept conceptUriObject;
    //public Concept conceptUriPredicate;


    @RelatedTo(type = "conceptUriSubject", elementClass = Concept.class)
    Set<Concept> conceptUriSubject;
```

Now the question, which actually are two questions:

A) `@RelatedTo(type =    "conceptUriSubject", elementClass =  Concept.class)` gives me error on    Eclipse, and advises me to add a    cast, but this doesn't solve the    error. I don't know if I must an    annotation or any other additional   thing to `Class.java`

B) As I have specified, the primery key    is composed by 3 concepts, and    `ConceptPK.java` is required. JPA    modelling is ok, but I don't know how    to do the same in NOSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mujer,

your domain looks like it would be much easier modelled in the graph database itself. As it is RDF like triplets that are annotated here.

You are right in that Spring Data Graph right now does not support compound keys. We will look into that in the future, but I can't promise anything.

In the graph you could model your nodes being Concepts (URIs) and the type of relationship representing what you want to represent with that Concept.

```
(TripleDBModel) - SUBJECT -> (Concept [URI = ""])
(TripleDBModel) - PREDICATE -> (Concept [URI = ""])
(TripleDBModel) - OBJECT -> (Concept [URI = ""])
(TripleDBModel) - HAS_ANNOTATION -> (Annotation)
```

This could be easily modelled with Spring Data Graph (or also with the pure Neo4j API)

```
@NodeEntity
class Concept {
   private URI uri;
}
@NodeEntity
class Triple {
   // will be automatically mapped to a relationship with the name "subject"
   private Concept subject;
   // or provide explicit mapping
   @RelatedTo(elementClass=Concept.class, type = "PREDICATE")
   private Concept predicate;
   private Concept object;

   @RelatedTo(elementClass=Annotation.class, type = "HAS_ANNOTATION")
   private Set<Annotation> annotations;
}
```

The eclipse error is annoying but just a wrong visualization, the AspectJ team is in the process of fixing that.

Hope that helps, if you need further advice just ask

Michael

Answer (score 2):

Well, you haven't said *which* NoSQL engine you're going to, which is pretty important. Most NoSQL data stores don't support the concept of a composite primary key - and some of them won't allow you unique columns in the first place.

First, note that I work for a NoSQL vendor, http://gigaspaces.com/ - I'm not unbiased.

However, going from JPA to NoSQL is not hard, no matter what your engine is. For GigaSpaces, you can use JPA to talk to the data grid with very few changes, for example, although then you're still stuck with JPA.

To really think about JPA, you need to think about your data as *data* and not organizational stuff; you have a triplet, basically, which means your NoSQL data items consist of three data items (predicate, subject, object, like you've used.) For most NoSQL engines you'll probably want an id there, too, just for efficiency's sake.

The ID is the "primary key," and enforcing unique triplets after that is going to be on *your* end more than the NoSQL engine's end; this is one area where NoSQL "suffers" compared to SQL, but it's also where you find the greatest speed and storage improvements.

For some NoSQL engines, then, you'll build a document, consisting of the three data items, and you'd just query for that document before writing it into the database.

I could give you an example for many NoSQL engines (and certainly can for GigaSpaces) but I don't know which one you're targeting or why.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am using Spring Data Graph, and the neo4j, and I have read that composed Id aren't allowed. Your idea of having an Id is not exaclty what I need, because I need to prove that there are no equal triplets.

Comment: You'd have to start a transaction, run a query, update the data if the query fails, in that case. Neo4J is okay, although obviously I prefer our own product. :)

Comment: I can imagine... :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Kundera.

http://mevivs.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/how-to-crud-and-jpa-association-handling-using-kundera/

Use JPA over NoSql

Answer (score 1):

PlayOrm is another solution which is JPA-like but with noSQL specific features like you can do @NoSqlEmbedded on a List of Strings and it is embedded in that row leading to a table where each row is a different length than the other rows...this is a noSql common pattern which is why NoSql ORM's need a slight break from JPA.

PlayOrm also supports joins and S-SQL (scalable SQL).

later,
Dean